# Play Framework Documentation 2.2.0

Tags: playframework, documentation

In previous versions the distribution of the Play Framework contained a documentation directory and all the material was accessible in the browser, through port 9000, whenever a play application was started.

Where can I find the documentation for version 2.2.0, which no longer provides this functionality?

Comment: What's wrong with http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Home?

Comment: This is fine if development is done online. I posed my question because I would like to have access to it off line, as in previous versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still on its place: `http://localhost:9000/@documentation` just make sure that you're running your app in **dev** mode with ie.: `play run` command.

Comment: You are right. I had to get online since starting was not possible without Play automatically downloading some resources it was missing. There still is no documentation directory but local help is available.